# WPF MVVM Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am following this example, to get started with MVVM

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/03/13/understanding_2d00_the_2d00_basics_2d00_of_2d00_mvvm_2d00_design_2d00_pattern.aspx

However my data is not shown in the textbox in the mainwindow

In the mainwindow.cs, I have this line of code

```
this.DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
```

In the mainwindow.xaml I have this line:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,23,0,0" Name="textBoxTitle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="206" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
```

However the title does not show in the textbox. Stepping through the code, shows the data in the DataContext. How can I get the title to display?

Comment: Have you implemented the `INotifyProperyChanged` interface?

Comment: In that example `MainPageViewModel` exposes list of `Books`. `MainPageViewModel` doesn't have property `Title`, `Book` class have. Is it the same case in your code? If so `Books` should be first bound to some `ListBox` or other `ItemsControl` in which you can show `Title` for each `Book`